# php make a json object not working as expected

Tags: php, json

This is my code:

```
$amenitiesObject = array('parameter-amenities' => array('value' =>  $amenities));
$buildingObject = array('parameter-building' => array('value' =>  $building));

$data = array($amenitiesObject, $buildingObject);
$post_data = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
return $post_data;
```

the result is:

```
{"0":{"parameter-amenities":{"value":""}},"1":{"parameter-building":{"value":""}}}
```

while i was hoping for this:

```
{"parameter-amenities":{"value":""},"parameter-building":{"value":""}}
```

what is my mistake please?

Comment: `$data = array_merge( $amenitiesObject, $buildingObject );`

Comment: @fusion3k yes works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

While @fusion3k's comment is correct and doing `$data = array_merge( $amenitiesObject, $buildingObject );` fixes it, I'd like to explain it a little further so you can avoid this type of scenario.

When you do `$data = array($amenitiesObject, $buildingObject);`, you are not creating a merge of both arrays, you are creating an array with index 0 equals to `$amenitiesObject` and index 1 equals to `$buildingObject`, the equivalent of doing :

```
array(0 => $amenitiesObject, 1 => $buildingObject);
```

So the `json_encode` part is working as expected.

When you use array_merge, you maintain only ONE array, that is a combination on both arrays, so you have the expected result.